# how to set int value with table name in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a `Master` table in sql server
 and i am using stored procedure with @val variable
and passing @val = `001 002 003...` and i want to add 
`001 002 003...` variables with `Mastertable` name like

```
Master001  Master002  Master003
```

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what you want to achieve? Do you want to "clone" your `master` table creating new tables `Master001`, `Master002`, and so on?

Comment: If you val is 001 your variable is a string (varchar) because if it was an int, it would remove leading zeros. So i think you can just write Master001 without any problem. If i understand your question, however it is a bit unclear!